# in geb how to get the label after input

Tags: html, groovy, geb

I'm working in Geb and I want to be able to grab the label with text "SS". How do I do this?

The HTML file with this block in the middle and multiple others like it that I want access to:

```
<span>
<input id="RunTimeSecond" name="RunTimeSecond" class="element text " size="2" type="text" maxlength="2" value="00">
<label>SS</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
$("input").next("label")
```

It's all in the navigation section if the Book of Geb

http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#navigator